# How to send a shape object from Excel in the body of an Email?

Tags: excel, image, vba, email, outlook

I'm struggling with this one (seemingly) simple step in a macro I'm trying to write. I have a Excel shape object that I'm trying to copy then paste into an outlook mail item. The shape object is actually a product of using Excel's "camera tool." What I did was created a chart that I need to flip 90 degrees for viewing. The camera tool makes that simple. The only problem I have is now pasting this picture shape into the outlook item. Suggestions?

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub emailer()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim p As Shape
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Dim om As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rec As Outlook.Recipient
Dim recs As Outlook.Recipients

'create the outlook session
Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'create the message
Set om = o.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set recs = om.Recipients
Set rec = recs.Add("email@email.com")
rec.Type = 1

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart_Pic")

Set p = ws.Shapes("Picture 2")
p.CopyPicture


With om
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.com"
.Subject = "Subject"
.HTMLBody = "This is a test" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & [where I want the shape to go]


For Each rec In om.Recipients
rec.Resolve
Next

om.Send

End With

Set o = Nothing
```

Comment: It is not that simple to actually embed an image into an HTML mail. You can either convert your shape into an image and store the image file (*.jpg, *.gif, *.png ...) on some publicly accessible file server and write an image link into your mail. Or you convert the image file in Base64 and "embedd" it. Details are [here](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts)

Comment: I appreciate the response. But why is it so simple then to manually Ctrl+C "copy" the image from the excel workbook and Ctrl+V "paste" it into a new mail item in Outlook?

Comment: I am not sure, but behind the scenes, the shape is probably copied as Windows Metafile (WMF, EMF) structure as vector graphics to the clipboard. From there it is pasted to the HTML mail body by converting it to a pixel image and to base64 as described im my comment. Try to send/receive a mail and analyse the contained HTML text to find out details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the clipboard for copy/paste the picture. But for this you need an Outlook mail editor which can deal with the clipboard. WordEditor for example.

Example:

```
Sub emailer()

 Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook
 Set oWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart_Pic")

 Set oPic = oWS.Shapes("Picture 2")
 oPic.CopyPicture ' oPic is now in Clipboard


 With oOlMItem

  .Display

  .To = "email@email.com"
  .Subject = "Subject"

  Set oOlInsp = .GetInspector
  Set oWdDoc = oOlInsp.WordEditor ' get Word Document from the MailBody

  Set oWdContent = oWdDoc.Content
  oWdContent.InsertParagraphBefore
  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
  oWdRng.InsertBefore "This is a test"
  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range
  oWdRng.Paste ' paste from oPic Clipboard

  olFormatHTML = 2
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' change to HTML


 End With

End Sub
```